# Why can't googlebot fetch my JavaScript file?

Tags: http-headers, googlebot

```
https://api-staging-weld.freetls.fastly.net/scripts/customdomain_weld.19f3e9ec.js
```

The error I get in Google Search Console is `Temporarily unreachable`    with no further explanation. I think it's something with my http headers but can't figure out which one. Here they are:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
age: 4905
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 29990
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 12:46:37 GMT
etag: W/"1a018-162e269bfe0"
last-modified: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 09:36:44 GMT
server: Cowboy
status: 200
vary: Accept-Encoding
via: 1.1 vegur
via: 1.1 varnish
x-cache: HIT
x-cache-hits: 1
x-powered-by: Express
x-served-by: cache-bma7030-BMA
x-timer: S1524228398.925110,VS0,VE6
```

What's wrong or what am i Missing?